# How to make a Panel in Tablelayout fill whole layout when maximized?

Tags: zk

`Panel` In `Portallayout` can be maximized to the `Portalchildren` or layout itself by default.

How can I make a `Panel` in `Tablelayout` can be maximized to the layout as well ?

Answer (score -1):

it's working for me.

```
<portallayout id="myptl" maximizedMode="whole">
            <portalchildren style="padding: 5px" width="450px" id="column1">
                <panel height="400px" title="Pie Chart Demo" border="normal"
                    collapsible="true" maximizable="true" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                    <panelchildren>
                        <iframe width="100%" height="100%"
                            src="/monitors/pie_chart_demo.zul" />
                    </panelchildren>
                </panel>
            </portalchildren>
    </portallayout>
```

Comment: I know that works, that's why I am asking about `Tablelayout` :P

Comment: no you can not do for Tablelayout. because tablelayout work as a xhtml tabe.

Comment: That's why I ask the question.

Comment: hey. you can override your TableLayoout class then customize your Component help of http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Guide/Fundamental_ZK/ZK_User_Interface_Markup_Language/ZK_Attributes#The_use.2C_apply_Attribute